# Quando surgiu o «o» que sói acompanhar a interrogativa «que»?

Tags: mudanças-históricas, perguntas

É muito frequente (até quase obrigatório, segundo vejo dalguns dialetos) ouvir a palavra «o» antes da palavra «que» nas perguntas. Por exemplo:

> O que queres?

Mas este «o» não parece ter nenhum valor significativo, por que também podemos dizer sem mudar o significado simplesmente

> Que queres?

Podemos ver a mesma situação nestas perguntas:

> (O) que vamos fazer?
>   (O) que estudas?
>   (O) que é isto?

Parece-me que o «o» será inovação portuguesa, porque não está presente nas línguas irmãs (nem mirandês nem, até sei eu, o galego).

Então, a minha pergunta é:

- Quando surgiu este O na língua?

Comment: No entanto, quando o "que" é seguido de um pronome pessoal, o artigo não parece ser dispensável:  "que ela disse?" , "que ele quer?", "que nós vamos fazer?".

Comment: @Centaurus em português europeu é perfeitamente dispensável: «Que disse ela?", "Que quer ele?", "Que é/foi que disse ela/ela disse?". Como pronome interrogativo não me ocorre nenhuma situação em que seja obrigatório. Já como pronome relativo, pode ser obrigatório: «ela não chegou ainda, o que é estranho», «devolve-me o que te emprestei».

Comment: @Artefacto acho que Centaurus estava a dizer quando é seguido inmediatemente pelo pronome.  É dizer, «O que ela disse?» mas «(O) que disse ela?».  Igual, acho eu que a posição do pronome é um das diferenças principais entre o brasileiro e o europeu.

Comment: «O que ela disse?» é agramatical em português europeu, foi por isso que alterei a frase. Mas nas interrogativas indiretas valem as duas ordens e aí já tenho mais dúvidas, de facto: «Perguntei-lhe que ganharia ela com isso» parece-me bom, mas «perguntei-lhe o que ela ganharia com ela ganharia com isso» melhor que «perguntei-lhe que ela ganharia com isso».

Comment: @Artefacto  Eu me referi aos meus exemplos, com as palavras na ordem em que estão escritas (pronome interrogativo + pronome pessoal + verbo) e não com o pronome depois do verbo:  "que ela disse?"  não me parece idiomático em pt-BR.

Comment: Guifa, o Mirandês não é bem uma língua irmã do Português. É uma língua [Astur-Leonesa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asturo-leon%C3%AAs). (não sei bem como pôr isto.)

Comment: Eu também evitaria usar "sói" no título, mas não achei que seria correto eu editar isso; sugiro-te "Quando surgiu o «o» que **costuma** acompanhar a interrogativa «que»?"

Comment: @Aneves para mim uma língua irmã seria uma língua ibérica ocidental, tipo galego, asturiano, aragonês, etc. (e por casualidade estou na mesma Miranda de l Douro enquanto escrevo tudo isto haha)

Comment: Ah, continuas empenhado(a?) em recuperar o verbo *soer*! Miranda do Douro?! Deve tar aí um calor abrasador!

Comment: @Jacinto acho que todos temos uma ou duas destas palavras que queremos recuperar :-)  Em espanhol para mim é *acaecer* (*acontecer*) e *cúyo* (*de quem*) e em inglês seria *thrice* (*tres vezes*) mais as antigas interrogativas *wherefore* (*para que*) e *whither* (*a/até onde*).  Não faz tanto calor como no país onde os índices superaram fácilmente os 45º C por causa da humedad e temperaturas aproximando os 40º assim aguento ha.  E cua comida mirandesa, voi quedar mui gordo... stá riquíssima!

Comment: Pois é. As minhas são *caráter* (letra, algarismo, etc., em vez de *carater*) e *bicha* (fila, fora do Brasil).

Answer (score 4):

O filólogo brasileiro Manuel Said Ali explora precisamente essa questão na *Gramática Histórica da Língua Portuguesa* (1931, p. 116-9). Diz ele (grafia original):

> Os pronomes interrogativos da lingua portugueza desde os seus primeiros tempos são : *quem, qual, que*. Como equivalente de *que* (= que cousa), e em certos casos preferida, surdiu e fixou-se em portuguez hodierno a forma tonica *o que*. [p. 116]

Os exemplos mais antigos que ele dá da nova forma *o que* são do século XVI:

> *O que* farey a estes rostos que tão asinha se mudam? (Sá de Mir[anda] 2, 98) — Riqueza ou grande poder, ou muita alta senhoria , ou bonança ou alegria, pois logo deixa de ser, quando era, *o que* seria ? (G[il] Vic[ente] 3, 344) — Ora, senhor, *o que* dizeis ? (A[ntónio] Prestes, 199) — Agora *o que* has de fazer? (ib. 490) — *O que* hão botas com chinelas? (ib. 159) — Moço, isto *o que* quer ser? (ib. 315). [p. 119]

Estes exemplo são todos de falas de personagens em peças de teatro. Exemplos vindos da voz do próprio escritor, os mais antigos que Said Ali nos dá são já do século XIX (ele diz que não se encontram exemplos na escrita de autores dos séculos XVI XVII, mas nada diz do XVIII). Disto conclui Said Ali que o interrogativo *o que* era parte da língua falada já no século XVI, mas que a língua literária, conservadora, demorou a adotá-lo.

O autor avança uma explicação para a inovação.  Esta terá ocorrido primeiro nas “interrogações indiretas”. Numa frase como “Sei eu bem *que* [= o que] vus van dizer” (p. 118, [cantiga de amor do sXIII](https://cantigas.fcsh.unl.pt/cantiga.asp?cdcant=122&pv=sim)), há potencialmente duas interpretações: *que* pode ser conjunção integrante — *sei bem que vos vão dizer [algo];* ou pode ser pronome — *sei bem o que vos vão dizer*. Então:

> Em muitos casos o sentido era dubio, ou pelos menos confuso […] D’ahi a necessidade de um expediente, e este expediente se encontrou nas expressões *a cousa que, aquillo que*, ou, mais simplesmente, *o que*.
>
> […]
>
> Admittida a forma *o que* na interrogação indirecta, estava dado o primeiro passo para a sua admissão nas perguntas directas. Aqui de facto penetrou, menos pelo sentido dubio da forma primitiva do que por uma questão de ordem phonetica. *Que* tornara-se vocabulo atono ou quase atono; *o que* possuia accentuação forte, que conservou até hoje. [p. 118]