# difference between "que fazes?" and "o que fazes" - why "o" at the beginning?

Tags: perguntas

When talking, instead of using the question word "que", one may use "o que" - I would like to understand this use of the article

Comment: Who's downvoting all the questions? Could the downvoter make a positive contribution and explain the downvote and whether/how the question could be improved?

Answer (score 7):

*Que fazes?* and *o que fazes?* mean the same. The interrogative ***que*** can be a determiner (when followed by a noun) or a pronoun (when it’s not, as in *que fazes?*). As a pronoun you can use ***que*** or ***o que*** ― there’s no difference; as a determiner you can use ***que*** only.

### Interrogative determiner ― *que* only

When ***que*** is followed by a noun:

> Que livros recomendas? [What books do you recommend? Never **o que livros*...]
>
> Que desculpa deu ele desta vez? [What excuse did he give this time? Never **o que desculpa*...]
>
> Que tipo de pessoa é ele? [What kind of person is he? Never **o que tipo*...]
>
> Que horas são? [What time is it? Never **o que horas são?*]

These questions are often reinforced with ***é que**: que desculpa é que ele deu desta vez?*

### Interrogative pronoun — *que* or *o que*

When ***que*** is not followed by a noun:

> Que vais fazer? [What are you going to do?]
> O que vais fazer? [The same]
>
> Que te disse ele? [What did he tell you?]
> O que que te disse ele? [The same]
>
> Que tens tu que ver com isso? [What have you got do with it?]
> O que tens tu que ver com isso? [The same]

As in the previous section, these questions can be reinforced with *é que: que é que vais fazer?* or *o que é que vais fazer?*

Now, when it comes to most **indirect questions**, if you don’t use this *é que*, the ***o*** is all but compulsory:

> Já sei **o que** vais dizer. [I know what you’re going to say.]
>
> Já sei **o que é que** vais dizer. [The same]
>
> Já sei **que é que** vais dizer. [The same]

I’m not saying that *já sei que vais dizer* is, with the intended meaning above, incorrect, but it at the very least would be highly confusing, because it can also be interpreted as *I know that you’re going to say/tell [something]*, whereas if you use *o que* (or add *é que*) it is definitely *I know what you’re*… In fact linguist Manuel Said Ali says that ***o que*** was invented to clear ambiguity in indirect questions like *sei que vais dizer* in old Portuguese. (You have [this question and answer](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6100/quando-surgiu-o-o-que-s%C3%B3i-acompanhar-a-interrogativa-que) on the origin of *o que*, but it is in Portuguese; I’ll translate it if you wish.)

Just *que* can still be used in a couple of indirect questions. The ones that come to mind are *não sei que te diga* (I don’t know what to say (to you)) and *não sei que faça* (I don’t know what to do). These are sort of formulaic; and you can also use *o que* instead.

In former times some authors have objected to the interrogative *o que* (*o que* was a popular innovation that writers took centuries to adopt; see [this question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/6100/quando-surgiu-o-o-que-s%C3%B3i-acompanhar-a-interrogativa-que)). This view still surfaces in some “educational” websites (like [this one](http://www.tudosobreconcursos.com/materiais/portugues/usos-da-palavra-que)), but the issue has long been settled. For instance Celso Cunha and Lindley Cintra (*Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*, Lisboa, 2014, p. 442) simply note that objections to *o que* in questions are groundless, and this view has been held by influential linguists since the 1800s.

Comment: _Já sei que vais dizer_ sounds OK to me. Not the most canonical way, for sure, but it doesn't sound strange. It's easy to find examples: _O que é mais preocupante, em sua opinião, é que não sabemos que é que pode suceder amanhã_ (CETEMPúblico), _não sei que mais possa dizer_.

Comment: @Artefacto, OK, so only potentially confusing: you have to get to the end of the sentence to find out wether *que* is pronoun or conjunction. But I''m perfectly OK with *já sei que é que vais dizer*. The dummy *é que* marks the sentence as an indirect question; in your example too.

Answer (score 4):

#### English

In spoken and written Portuguese, the word “que” has four different functions: an interrogative pronoun, a relative pronoun, a conjunction or an adverb; some grammarians say that it can also be a preposition, as in “ter que” instead of “ter de”, but that is controversial. As an adverb, I did not find a source, but I can say that it sounds strange to add an article when “que” is used as an adverb. *Que supresa!* (*What a surprise!*) sounds normal, but *O que surpresa!* (*What a surprise*) sounds strange and saying it might sound like *Oh, que surpresa!* (*Ah, what a surprise!*).

### Relative Pronoun

As a relative pronoun, the [Houssaiss](https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v5-4/html/index.php#2) dictionary give an example, *as mãos tremiam freneticamente, o que denunciava a sua culpa* (*The hands shook frenetically, which gave him/her away*), which indirectly says that the relative pronoun “que” allows the use of a definite article.

It is not allowed in every situation. When it is allowed, it can usually be translated as “which”.

### Interrogative Pronoun

[[2](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/que-ou-o-que/14529)] Both ways are correct, but “que” is considered purer, and some grammarians believe it is more correct, but both ways are very used and accepted by dictionaries; Priberam, for example.

As a personal note, I would like to say that I see more “que” in Portugal than in Brazil. I am Brazilian and for me, “o que” is the usual and formal form, and “que” looks more informal and like the speaker is removing the “o“

### Conjunction

In all examples I found with “que” in dictionaries (Priberam and Houssaiss) as a conjunction, the conjunction “que” couldn't be turned into “o que” without changing the sentence's meaning or making the sentence sound wrong. Therefore, I believe that it is not good practice to add the definite article “o” before “que” when “que” is a conjunction.

#### Português

A palavra “que” tem quatro classificações: pronome interrogativo, pronome relativo, conjunção e advérbio; alguns gramáticos põem “que” como preposição por causa de “ter que” em vez de “ter de”, mas é controvérso. Como advérbio não encontrei nenhuma fonte, mas eu posso dizer que me soa estranho adicionar um artigo a “que” quando advérbio; *O que surepresa* soa estranho, por exemplo.

### Pronome Relativo

Como pronome relativo, o dicionário [Houssaiss](https://houaiss.uol.com.br/corporativo/apps/uol_www/v5-4/html/index.php#2) tem um exemplo, *as mãos tremiam freneticamente, o que denunciava a sua culpa*, o que indiretamente diz que o pronome relativo “que” pode receber artigo definido, mas nem sempre.

### Pronome Interrogativo

[[2](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/que-ou-o-que/14529)] Ambas as formas estão corretas, mas “que” é considerado mais puro e alguns gramáticos consideram-no mais correto, mas ambas são muito usadas e aceitas por dicionários; Priberam, por exemplo..

Como nota pessoa, Eu gostaria de dizer que eu vejo mais “que” em Portugal que no Brasil. Eu sou brasileiro e para mim, “o que” é a formal comum e formal, e “que” tem uma impressão mais informal e soa como o falante está removendo o “o”.

### Conjunção

Em todos os exemplos que encontrei com “que” como conjunção em dicionários (Priberam e Houssaiss), a conjunção “que” não pode ser trocada por “o que” sem que ou mude o sentido ou pareça errado. Então, creio que não é boa prática escrever o artigo “o” atrás da conjunção “que”.

Comment: «Em "as mãos tremiam freneticamente, o que denunciava a sua culpa (The hands shook frenetically, what told her/his fault), which indirectly says that the relative pronoun “que” allows the use of a definite article.» Neste caso (relativas explicativas) _o que_ é obrigatório; não podes substituir por apenas _que_.

Comment: Schilive, I've fixed some words in your first paragraph to make it sound more idiomatic.  If you don't like it, you can always roll it back to what it was.

Comment: @Centaurus, it is better in my opinion. Thanks!

Comment: The relative pronoun is beyond the scope of the question, but as you brought it up, the difference between *que* and *o que* is as follows. *Que* refers to an item in the previous clause: *ele insistiu em pagar o jantar, **que** por sinal estava muito bom -- que* refers to *jantar*; you can't use *o que* to refer to jantar. *O que* refers to the entire clause: *ele insistiu em pagar o jantar, **o que** muito me surpreedeu* -- ele ter insistido em pagar o jantar surpreendeu-me; you can't use just *que* to refer to the entire clause.

Comment: @Jacinto, thanks. I couldn't find neither a way to explain it or a explanation. Thanks. I'll add it up later.